# Integrating Azure AD authentication in ASP.NET Core boilerplate

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, abp

I downloaded the free template from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates (ASP.NET Core with Angular SPA) and am now trying to integrate Azure AD authentication. I have tried some examples provided by Microsoft and these all work, however, I am unable to get it working with this template.

Can anyone guide me through on how to set this up using the ABPAuthorize attribute? I am currently getting a valid JWT token from the login service, but when using this token, I am getting a 403 forbidden error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us what examples have you tried?

Comment: Hey Ricardo. I tried the following example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

It created a new app registration and I could download a solution. When running the solution, this worked. I then copied all necessary configuration and code from the sample to the template I downloaded, but it was not working.

Comment: Can you share your code trough github or similar? I cannot find the ABPAuthorize (attribute?).

Comment: So the AbpAuthorize attribute is something from the template. Source code from the aspnetcoreboilerplate template can be found here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/tree/dev/src. The examples from Microsft are using the standard Authorize attributes to secure the endpoints. 

My question relates to this post: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5155
Im having the same issue, where I'm trying to use the JWT token generated by AZure AD to authenticate. But my guess is that the AbpAuthorize attribute is checking some other stuff as well.

Comment: @JorenSynaeve ok i will take a look and come back to you.

Comment: @JorenSynaeve please provide the full error response details.

Comment: @JorenSynaeve and how're you adding the ABPAuthorize to your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same problem.
I came up with this idea, but it solve just part of the problem.
After you should be able to connect with controller via Azure AD

1. Add to appsettings.json

```
  "Authentication": {
    "AzureAd": {
      "IsEnabled": "true",
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Domain": "myDomain.onmicrosoft.com",
      "TenantId": "57****t6",
      "ClientId": "8a***44",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    }
```

2. Install nuget package
   **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI** to **YourNamespace.Web.Host**
3. Add to Startup.cs
    **`app.UseAuthorization();`** 
   e.g.:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
}
```

4. Add to AuthConfigurer.cs

```
public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    if (bool.Parse(configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:IsEnabled"]))
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAd", options));

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        });
    }            ...
}
```

5. Add to controller AuthorizeAttribute:

   **`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)]`**

   e.g.:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class HelloController : LouncherPadControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello, this controller works!";
    }
}
```

6. Then pass the token in the header

### TODO:

Verify or register user in ABP framework